# RecyclerView onLongClickListener refuse to trigger

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener, android-recyclerview, onitemlongclicklistener

I want to implement a long press of a CardView inside a RecyclerView

The layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

I tried this:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Utils.context));
mRecyclerView.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(Utils.context,"dsfd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And I also tried to implement this event in the RecyclerView.ViewHolder class but nothing works. I have the long press effect but the event itself is not triggered. There is no onItemLongClickListener. I also tried this: [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick/26826692#26826692) .

What am I missing?

Comment: Put your listeners on the widgets in the `RecyclerView`, not on the `RecyclerView` itself. "I also tried this: RecyclerView onClick ." -- that seems to have the right answers.

Comment: Regarding the first part: You mean I should define a long click event for all widgets inside the card view? what if the user long presses outside of the widgets?

Comment: "Should it be on the recycler view or not?" -- sorry. Eng.Fouad's answer is not setting a long-click listener on the `RecyclerView`. His is adding an on-item-touch listener, one that is set up to detect clicks and long-clicks. If you want the whole item to be long-clickable, that's probably the best approach. If you only need part of the items to be long-clickable, put the listener on the widgets in the items.

Comment: I need the whole item to be clickable, I tried his approach and it didn't work but now I realized it was before I added android:longClickable="true" to the RecyclerView. I will try that now, though it seems like a hack more than an intuitive solution.

Comment: Some of the other answers should be relevant, such as the suggestion to use TwoWayView, if you are having problems with Eng.Fouad's answer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Using this method while the view has its own event seems like a workaround of a bug.

Comment: Funny but now I wonder how to make a certain widget inside the clickable cardview consume the click and the cardview should ignore it, any idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486763/android-clicking-on-a-widget-inside-a-clickable-cardview

Answer (score 3):

You can create Interface where you should implement your onLongClicked(int position) method. And use it.
Follow this steps to create your onLongClickListener:

Create your Interface:

```
public interface IRecyclerViewClickListener {

   void onLongClicked(int position); 
}
```

Create listener object in your activity/fragment and pass this listener object to your adapter in the create adapter method. Example:

```
// ... some code ...
adapter = new MoviesListAdapter(getActivity(), list, listener);
rvDialogs.setAdapter(adapter);
// ... code ...
```

In your adapter in your owned ViewHolder constructor set long listener on itemView:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Title;
        // ...

        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDialogTitle);
            // ...

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    listener.onLongClicked(getAdapterPosition());
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

After in your activity/fragment setup your IListener:

```
listener = new IRecyclerViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongClicked(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
```

Hope it help you! Good luck and sorry for my bad english ;)